# Check if all values in a column falls into a specific group

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I have the following table:

```
+-------+
| Token |
+=======+
| A     |
+-------+
| B     |
+-------+
| B     |
+-------+
| C     |
+-------+
| A     |
+-------+
| X     |
+-------+
```

and I want to check ALL values of the column 'Token' and return a flag string to designate what condition is met:

- when all records are in group (A, B) --> return `'Condition1'`,

  - examples:

    ```
    AABAAB: true
    AAAAAA: false
    BBBBBB: false
    AABBAC: false
    ```
- when all records are in group (A, B, C) --> return `'Condition2'`

  - examples:

    ```
    AABBAC: true
    AABAAB: false
    AAAAAA: false
    BBBBBB: false
    AXBBAC: false
    ```

so I am  basically looking for a general SELECT statement that looks like:

```
      select case when exists ( select ....
                                  from test_table
                                 where  ....)  -- the SQL Statement that checks if Condition1 is met
                  then 'Condition1'
                  when exists ( select ....
                                  from test_table
                                 where ....) -- the SQL Statement that checks if Condition1 is met
                  then 'Condition1'
                  else 'NOTHING'
             end condition_met
        from dual;
```

or any other form of SQL that provide the desired results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `LISTAGG()` aggregate function to get all the distinct values of `Token` as a comma separated list and check the result in a `CASE` expression:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT LISTAGG(Token, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Token) Tokens
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Token FROM tablename) t
)
SELECT CASE Tokens
  WHEN 'A,B' THEN 'Condition1'
  WHEN 'A,B,C' THEN 'Condition2'
  ELSE 'Nothing'
END condition_met  
FROM cte
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=2737cb1ca7713a82b19898ad60c05b7b).

Note that in recent versions of Oracle you can include `DISTINCT` inside `LISTAGG()`:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT LISTAGG(DISTINCT Token, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Token) Tokens
  FROM tablename
)
....................................
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just use a `case` expression:

```
select (case when sum(case when token = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
                  sum(case when token = 'B' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
                  sum(case when token = 'C' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
                  sum(case when token not in ('A', 'B', 'C') then 1 else 0 end) = 0
             then 'Condition ABC'
             when sum(case when token = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
                  sum(case when token = 'B' then 2 else 0 end) > 0 and
                  sum(case when token not in ('A', 'B') then 1 else 0 end) = 0
             then 'Condition AB'
        end)
from test_table
```

Comment: Thank you but it's failing when there are an outsider character, for example: AABABX -> it returns 'Condition AB' while it should return null. and the same applies for ABCABX --> returning 'Condition AABC' while null is expected.

Comment: @EzzedeenSaghier . . . That is easily fixed by adding an additional condition.

Answer (score 0):

Try counting the number of A's, B's, and C's:

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN Total = A + B -- Optional: AND A > 0 AND B > 0
            THEN 'Condition1'
            WHEN Total = A + B + C -- Optional: AND A > 0 AND B > 0 AND C > 0
            THEN 'Condition2'
            ELSE 'NOTHING'
       END AS Result
  FROM ( SELECT SUM(CASE Token WHEN 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS A
              , SUM(CASE Token WHEN 'B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS B
              , SUM(CASE Token WHEN 'C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS C
              , COUNT(*) AS Total
           FROM test_table ) X
```